# Zoom inconsistency between IOS and Android Google Maps SDKs

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

We are developing navigation app for both IOS and Android platforms.

On IOS I restrict map zoom levels by `mapView.setMinZoom(4, maxZoom: 16)`. To load map tiles I use GMSSyncTileLayer as tiles are stored locally. What I found weird that in function `tileFor(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt)` I get zoom levels 5 ... 17 which is offsetted by 1 comparing to range of allowed zooms I set (4 ... 16).

On Android I restrict map zoom levels by

```
map.setMinZoomPreference(4)
map.setMaxZoomPreference(16)
```

To load map tiles I use TileProvider to load custom map tiles. In TileProvider's function `getTile(x: Int, y: Int, zoom: Int): Tile?`, however, I get correct range of zoom levels (4 ... 16) opposing to IOS version of app.

I believed that TileProvider and GMSSyncTileLayer are analogous functionality wise. Can anyone explain me why I get different zoom level range?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We are facing the same issue with my team currently. Did you ever figure it out?